# How do you create a "count" matrix from a series?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas series of lists of categorical variables. For example:

```
df = pd.Series([["A", "A", "B"], ["A", "C"]])
```

Note that in my case the series is pretty long (50K elements) and the number of possible distinct elements in the list is also big (20K elements).

I would like to obtain a matrix having a column for each distinct feature and its count as value. For the previous example, this means:

```
[[2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

This is the same output as the one obtained with OneHot encoding, except that it contains the count instead of just 1.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `explode`:

```
df.explode().groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  2  1  0
1  1  0  1
```

To get the list of list, chain the above with `.values`:

```
array([[2, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```

Note that you will end up with a `50K x 20K` array.